# Fedora 16 - Iptables installed, but no iptables service available

Tags: fedora, iptables

I'm trying to open ports on my fedora OS.

In the past, this was as easy as adding an rule like

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

I went to restart my iptables service and there is none.  I went to install iptables and yum says it's installed and up to date (version 1.4.x)

How do I get the service?

EDIT: The answer is below, but I also wanted to let people know, if you're having trouble adding the rule to the /etc/sysconfig/iptables config... I would recommend using the $> system-config-firewall command to bring up a gui port editor that appears to work with the command below to restart the ipstables service via systemctl

Comment: iptables is not a system service.  It is a frontend to the netfilter packet filter *inside* the kernel.  You shouldn't need to start it.

Comment: All the tutorials show me editing the /etc/sysconfig/iptables to add 80 accept as a rule..and then to restart that service-- How would I go about opening port 80?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Fedora 16, the approach to restart service has taken a giant (flighted) leap from SysV init script style to *systemd* approach.

To stop, disable, enable, start iptables service via `systemctl` command.

```
[root@fedora ~]# systemctl stop iptables.service 
[root@fedora ~]# systemctl stop ip6tables.service 
[root@fedora ~]# systemctl disable iptables.service 
rm '/etc/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/iptables.service'
[root@fedora ~]# systemctl disable ip6tables.service 
rm '/etc/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/ip6tables.service'
```

After configuring iptables rules, save them to some file like:

```
[root@fedora ~]# iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

Comment: also check out "systemctl list-units" for a list of all the things systemctl knows about.